# CSS transform: scale blurs image on hover

Tags: css, transform

I've setup a logo in our website's menubar so when a user hovers it has a slight scale up. However, the logo blurs simultaneously when it scales. Any suggestions?

```css
#logo a {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 55%;
  transform: scale(.95);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#logo a:hover {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <a href="https://www.umu.ajt.mybluehost.me/opencart/index.php?route=common/home"><img src="https://www.umu.ajt.mybluehost.me/opencart/image/catalog/logo/logo.png" title="BumperPlugs.com" alt="BumperPlugs.com" class="img-responsive"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's actually blur, and not just the image being lower resolution than the size it's being shown at? (Are the `filter` props in the hover style an attempt to fix the issue? It doesn't seem necessary for what you're describing)

Comment: @DBS, look at these screenshots so you can see the before/after.
Before - https://i.paste.pics/591ad7abab6360bc9510baa7a4759012.png
After - https://i.paste.pics/5e34dfd82c5e424afe215cef84bfa886.png

Comment: That's a pretty small image to be scaling up....also you are still applying the blur.

Comment: You're simply scaling the image past its native resolution which makes it blurry. Make the non-hovered image slightly smaller and then scale it to 1 on hover. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yL19p530/

Comment: This is normal. You're scaling up an image beyond its original resolution. You can try to go from `scale(.95)` to `scale(1)`, might yield a better result!

Comment: @chriskirknielsen just made those edits, but that blur is still slightly visible.

Comment: @msklut it has to be blurry at some point given the size of the image, this why `svg` exist

Comment: @ZohirSalak, OK. Makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this. It should solve this issue.**

```css
#logo a {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 55%;
  transform: scale(.95);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#logo a img{
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   transform: translateZ(0);
}


#logo a:hover {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <a href="https://www.umu.ajt.mybluehost.me/opencart/index.php?route=common/home"><img src="https://www.umu.ajt.mybluehost.me/opencart/image/catalog/logo/logo.png" title="BumperPlugs.com" alt="BumperPlugs.com" class="img-responsive"></a>
</div>
```